java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Please don't pass mock here. Spy is not allowed on mock. for ParameterizedTest
I have following test:
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.MOCK)
@WebAppConfiguration
class MyTest {
    @MockitoSpyBean
    protected lateinit var ldapConnectionPoolHolder: LdapConnectionPoolHolder
    
    @BeforeEach
    fun setup() {
        connectionPoolSpy = spy(ldapConnectionPoolHolder.getConnectionPool())
        doReturn(connectionPoolSpy).whenever(ldapConnectionPoolHolder).getConnectionPool()
        connectionSpy = spy(connectionPoolSpy.getConnection()) // this line leads to error sometimes
        doReturn(connectionSpy).whenever(connectionPoolSpy).getConnection()
    }

    @ParameterizedTest("...")
    @MethodSource("withoutCookiesSuccessScenarios")
    fun myTest(...) {
    }

for even iterations I see an error:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Please don't pass mock here. Spy is not allowed on mock.

    at org.mockito.Mockito.spy(Mockito.java:2246)
    at org.mockito.kotlin.SpyingKt.spy(Spying.kt:52)
enter code here


I tried to do Mockito.reset(connectionPoolSpy, connectionSpy)
in the end of the test but it doesn't help

Why do you have a @SpringBootTest AND Mockito spies/mocks? The former creates real Spring beans, the latter doesn't involve Spring at all.

connectionPoolSpy = spy(ldapConnectionPoolHolder.getConnectionPool());       doReturn(connectionPoolSpy).whenever(ldapConnectionPoolHolder).getConnectionPool() makes little sense. First, you call the real method and create a spy copy of the returned instance. In the second statement, you stub the call to return the spy that you just copied. The next time the setup method will run, ldapConnectionPoolHolder.getConnectionPool() will return the spy that you have previously stubbed. What is ldapConnectionPoolHolder exactly and why do you return spies from mocks?

@knittl the reals ldapConnectionPoolHolder could return different instances of  connectionPoolHolder so I try to forc it to always return the same object and I want to inspect it

I don't need to return spyes from mocks. I don't see any mocks at all

doReturn(…).when(mock).method() requires a mock object as argument to when. You cannot stub calls on non-mock objects.

@knittl spy technically is a mock

I know, but you claimed that ldapConnectionPoolHolder is not a mock. You even claimed that there are no mocks at all (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79307790/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-please-dont-pass-mock-here-spy-is-not-allo?noredirect=1#comment139854480_79307790)

@knittl hope we are on the same page now

The solution is adding
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.BEFORE_EACH_TEST_METHOD)

So test class definition will look like:
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.MOCK)
@WebAppConfiguration
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.BEFORE_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
class MyTest {

